# update field in DB symfony2

Tags: symfony

In my application I send Email and When the user clicks in URL the state of a field in DB  change(update).

in my controller I have:

```
 public function confirmeAction($username)
{
    $col = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('acmeCongeBundle:Collaborateur')->find($username);
    echo $col->getEmailCollaborateur();
    $conge = $this->get('gestion_conge.congeservice')->findCongeByCollaborateur($col);
    $id = 2;

    $conge->setEtatConge($this->get('etat.etatcongeservice')->findEtatById($id));

    return $this->render('acmeCongeBundle:Conge:confirmer.html.twig');
}
```

the controller that send the email:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('demande de conge sans solde')
    ->setFrom($col->getEmailCollaborateur())
    ->setTo($form->get("emailcdp")->getData())
    ->setBody($this->renderView('acmeCongeBundle:Conge:demandeCongeNormal.html.twig',array('conge' => $conge )));
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

and the demandeCongeNormal.html.twig contain:

```
{{ url('confirmer_conge' ,{'username':  id }) }}
```

I get the id of user that send the Email form URL and i want to update the State of entity Conge when the user clic on the url.

I have no exception but the state of setEtatConge doesn't change . how can I update the Field Etatfrom entity Conge (Conge exist in my DB)

Comment: `$conge` is probably null. Please check which of your previous expressions used to calculate `$conge` returns null (my guess goes to `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('acmeCongeBundle:Conge')->find($col)`)

Comment: yes it's null because i tried to write echo  $conge->getNbreJour(); it's give me nothing but i get the Colab ($col = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('acmeCongeBundle:Collaborateur')->find($username);)

Comment: Are you sure you have an acmeCongeBundle:Conge with the id of $col?

Comment: it's work for the first but why not for the second ?

Comment: yes i have the id of $Col in the entity Conge

Comment: To clarify - Conge.id = $Col, yes? not Conge.someOtherField.id = $Col

Comment: Now it's work i changed : $conge = $this->get('gestion_conge.congeservice')->findCongeByCollaborateur($col); .  but the problem i can't update EtatConge it dosen't change in my DB ??

Comment: Please update your question with current code and exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your confirmeAction, you should add:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($conge);
$em->flush();
```

To save the data.